# wxPython app (Not Responding) temporarly

Tags: python, http, urllib2, wxwidgets

A file selection triggers the code bellow.

This runs a loop pulsing the progress-bar while a thread runs a few `DELETE` requests.

Half way through the requests the window shows (Not responding) that goes away once the thread finishes and all goes back to normal.

What am I doing wrong and how can I get the (Not Responding) issue gone?

It's been driving me mental for hours trying to find the cause.

I think it's related to the requests but I cannot figure out how.

```
def Process(self, event):
    self._thread_end      = False
    self._process_success = False
    threading.Thread(target=self.ProcessThread).start()

    while not self._thread_end:
        time.sleep(0.05)
        self._gauge.Pulse()
    self._gauge.SetValue(0)
    self.PageResult(self._process_success)



def ProcessThread(self):
    try:
        csv_file = self._csv_dirname + '/' + self._csv_filename
        if os.path.isfile(csv_file):
            csv_contents = open(csv_file).read().replace('\r\n', '\n')
            csv_list     = filter(None, csv_contents.split('\n'))

            for entry in csv_list:
                http = urllib2.Request(self._logged_url + '/api/' + entry)
                http.get_method = lambda: 'DELETE'
                result = urllib2.urlopen(http)

        self._process_success = True
    except:
        self._process_success = False
        exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback = sys.exc_info()
        ExceptCatch(exc_type.__name__, exc_value, exc_traceback, threading.current_thread().name)
    self._thread_end = True
```

Comment: Funny thing. I just changed the progress-bar so that untill first request finishes it runs `Pulse` and after that it runs `SetValue` showing the percentage of requests that have been made of the total. (100 / total) * requests_made. Now I no longer get the (Not Responding) issue.

Comment: If the first request takes to long I still get it. This is irritating.